# Reserve cpu-time in multiprocessing or multithreading application

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I'm working on a project with a Raspberry Pi 3 for some environmental control with a number of simple recurring events in a continuous loop. The RP3 is way overqualified for this job, but it alows me focus on other stuff.

Characteristics of the application:

1. The application should collect sensordata (with variable interval n-seconds) from a dozen sensors (temperature, humidity, pH, ORP, etc).
2. Based on time and these sensordata, the controller calculates output (switches, valves and PWM-drivers).
3. Almost none events needs to run sequential.
4. Some events are in the category "safety" and should run instantly when triggered (fail-safe sensors, emergency button).
5. Most events run repetitive in a seconds interval (every second, till every 30 seconds).
6. Some events triggers an action, activating a relay during 1 to 120 seconds.
7. Some events use a time-bassed value. This value needs to be calculated several times a day and is fairly CPU intensive (uses a few itterative interpolating formula, and therefore has a variable runtime).
8. Display with environment status (in a continuous loop)

I'm familiar (not by profession) with VB.NET, but decided to do this project in Python 3.6.
The last few months I read a lot about subjecs like design patterns, threads, processes, events, paralel prcessing, etc.

Based on my reading I think Asyncio combined with some tasks in an Executor will do the job.

Most tasks/events are not time-critical. Controller output can use 'most recent' sensordata.
Some tasks, on the other hand, activating a relay for a certain period of time. I would like to know how to programm these tasks without the chance another 'time consuming' task is blocking the processor during the period of time (for example) a CO2 valve is open. This could be disastrous for my environment.

Herefore I need some advice.

See below for my code so far. I'm not sure I make correct use of the Asyncio functions in Python.
For the sake of readability, I will store the contents of the various tasks in separate modules.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
import time
import random
import math

# define a task...
async def firstTask():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("First task executed")

# define another task...        
async def secondTask():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Second Worker Executed")

# define/simulate heavy CPU-bound task
def heavy_load():
    while True:
        print('Heavy_load started')
        i = 0
        for i in range(50000000):
            f = math.sqrt(i)*math.sqrt(i)
        print('Heavy_load finished')
        time.sleep(4)

def main():

    # Create a process pool (for CPU bound tasks).
    processpool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()

    #  Create a thread pool (for I/O bound tasks).
    threadpool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        # Add all tasks. (Correct use?)
        asyncio.ensure_future(firstTask())
        asyncio.ensure_future(secondTask())
        loop.run_in_executor(processpool, heavy_load)
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        print("Loop will be ended")
        loop.close()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most tasks/events are not time-critical. Controller output can use 'most recent' sensordata. Some tasks, on the other hand, activating a relay for a certain period of time. I would like to know how to programm these tasks without the chance another 'time consuming' task is blocking the processor during the period of time (for example) a CO2 valve is open. This could be disastrous for my environment.

Allow me to stress that Python is **not a real-time language**, and asyncio is not a real-time component. They sport neither the infrastructure for real-time execution (Python is garbage collected and typically runs on time-shared systems), nor have they been tested in such environments in practice. Consequently I would strongly advise against using them in any scenario where a misstep could be *disastrous for your environment*.

With that out of the way, your code has a problem: while the `heavy_load` calculation will not block the event loop, it will never complete either, nor will it provide information on its progress. The idea behind `run_in_executor` is that the calculation you are running will eventually halt, and that the event loop will want to be notified about it. Idiomatic usage of `run_in_executor` could look like this:

```
def do_heavy_calc(param):
    print('Heavy_load started')
    f = 0
    for i in range(50000000):
        f += math.sqrt(i)*math.sqrt(i)
    return f

def heavy_calc(param):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_in_executor(processpool, do_heavy_calc)
```

The expression `heavy_calc(...)` not only runs without blocking the event loop, but it is also *awaitable*. That means that asynchronous code can await its result, also without blocking other coroutines:

```
async def sum_params(p1, p2):
    s1 = await heavy_calc(p1)
    s2 = await heavy_calc(p2)
    return s1 + s2
```

The above runs the two calculations one after the other. It can also be done in parallel:

```
async def sum_params_parallel(p1, p2):
    s1, s2 = await asyncio.gather(heavy_calc(p1), heavy_calc(p2))
    return s1 + s2
```

Another thing that could improve is the setup code:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(firstTask())
asyncio.ensure_future(secondTask())
loop.run_in_executor(processpool, heavy_load)
loop.run_forever()
```

Calling `asyncio.ensure_future` and then never awaiting the result is somewhat of an asyncio anti-pattern. Exceptions raised by unawaited tasks are silently swallowed, which is almost certainly not something you'd want. Sometimes people simply forget to write `await`, which is why asyncio complains about unawaited pending tasks when the loop is destroyed.

It is good coding practice to arrange for every task to be awaited by *someone*, either immediately with `await` or `gather` to combine it with other task, or at a later point. For instance, if the task needs to run in the background, you can store it somewhere and `await` or cancel it at the end of the application lifecycle. In your case, I would combine `gather` with `loop.run_until_complete`:

```
everything = asyncio.gather(firstTask(), secondTask(),
                           loop.run_in_executor(processpool, heavy_load))
loop.run_until_complete(everything)
```

Comment: I'm glad you stress that Python is not a real-time language. I think there are only a few language out there which can be seen as real-time.

Comment: @Rene2322 Thanks, but I'm also curious if my answer addressed your question?

Comment: For my application I only need a time significance in terms of seconds. What I would like to achieve is a small and more or less predictable latency. My valve needs to open for about 15 seconds +/- 2 seconds (with an avarage task latency of only a few milliseconds I think this should be easily achievable) This will be done by a sleep. There are 2 "heavy_load" tasks that possible coincide  once in a while. I think I will switch between these tasks. If heavy_load is running the sensitive task is not aloud.

Comment: About the awaiting results. Thanks for explaining. I try to grow quickly into this language. I'm not always sure I choose the right path. Thanks again. I continue programming.

Comment: @Rene2322 The most important thing to remember is never to do anything in the event loop thread that might block the event loop. In other words, `time.sleep()` is outright forbidden (use `await asyncio.sleep()`), and so is calling functions like `heavy_load()` directly (use executors, of which you are already aware). Your question shows that you know that, but it's important enough that it doesn't hurt to repeat it.

Comment: @Rene2322 Also, be wary of coroutines that do a lot of stuff (including `await`ing other coroutines) without waiting for IO or timeouts. An `await` *does not guarantee* an event loop context switch - for example, `while True: await noop()`, where `noop` is defined as `async def noop(): pass` **will** block the event loop. So the mere fact that something is an `async def` and has `await` sprinkled in its bottom-most loop doesn't mean that it allows anyone else to run. If in doubt, use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to allow other tasks to run.

Answer (score 0):

> Some events are in the category "safety" and should run instantly when triggered (fail-safe sensors, emergency button).

Then I strongly advise you to not rely on software to fulfil this function. Emergency stop buttons that cut off the power is the way that kind of thing is normally done. If you have software doing that, and you genuinely have a threat-to-life situation to handle, you're in for a whole pile of woe - there's almost certainly a ton of regulations with which you have to comply.

Comment: I'm afraid I wrote this down in a silly way. I understand emergency-buttons need to break a circuit hardware-based. It's more like I could have tons of tasks. A few of them are not scheduled, but triggerd by sensors. Those needs to processed first. Maybe I can prioritize them in a queue. If i'm right, asyncio supports a priority queue. I will look into that.

Comment: @Rene2322, that's a relief! As a general comment on prioritisation, I've often used thread priorities as a way of exploiting the OS's scheduler to do the decision making for me. Higher priority threads run first, and on a linux PREEMPT_RT kernel everything else will be forced out of the way as required, and works especially well with Actor Model architectures. As user4815162342 says above, Python isn't good for real time work, but as you're dealing with timescales of seconds you may be OK.